# Interfacing mysql and html using ajax: getting an "incorrect character" in the console

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my mysql database with an html page using an ajax script. Based on the tutorial from Adnan Afzal (http://adnan-tech.com/tutorial/get-data-from-database-using-ajax-javascript-php-mysql), I coded one php and one html file. However, each time I try to run the page, I get an error telling me that the first character at position 1 is not correct :

[image]

[image]

Here is a dump of my php (called data.php)

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
    array_push($data, $row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

Here is a dump of my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>id_country
    <th>Country_name_en
    <th>Country_name_fr
    </tr>
    <tbody id="data"></tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    ajax.send();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var html = "";
    for(var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    var id_country = data[a]['id_country'];
    var Country_name_en = data[a]['country_name_en'];
    var Country_name_fr = data[a]['country_name_fr'];        
    html += "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + id_country + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + Country_name_en + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + Country_name_fr + "</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML += html;
    }
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope the way the question is published is acceptable, I am not expecting to have code written on my behalf. I would be very keen on understanding what I am doing wrong here and hopefully, this post could be useful to anyone else.

Edit : Following the reply of Aynber, I have added a screenshot below of the debugging network tab :

[image]

Edit 2 : Following the reply of Shivendra Singh, I have corrected the code as follows :

```
var id_country = data[a]['id_country'];
var Country_name_en = data[a]['country_name_en'];
var Country_name_fr = data[a]['country_name_fr'];
```

Comment: Check the Network tab in your browser's Developer Console, and see what's being returned from your GET request.

Comment: What does the file `trial.txt` contain?  You write `$returnValue` to it, but not sure where that is being set.

Comment: @NigelRen: thanks. I've just realised this. So I got rid of these lines. Unfortunately it hasn't changed anything

Comment: I think data[a].Country_name_en should be data[a]['Country_name_en'] and same for Country_name_fr.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh: Thanks a lot. I made a progress thanks to your contribution.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Just a quick observation. You HTML is inside the <head> tag, it should be inside <body>

Comment: @VladimirSabo: thank you Vladimir, I have updated my code according to your comment. my bad

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot to the help of the contributors.

It was the syntax of how I was referring the fields which was not correct :

```
[...]
var Country_name_en = data[a]['country_name_en'];
[...]
```

I have corrected the code accordingly above to depict the correct situation.